# Difference of two sums of three squares

Tags: sums-of-squares

I have proved that every integer is the difference of two sums of three squares, i.e.,

$n = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - (d^2 + e^2 + f^2)$

Is this result publishable?

Answer (score 3):

You might enjoy the 1939 book by Leonard Eugene Dickson, called *Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers.* One of the things he does is find all quadratic forms in three variables that are "universal." One familiar example is $x^2 + y^2 - z^2.$

Answer (score 3):

Any integer not congruent to $2$ modulo $4$ can be written as the difference of two integer squares. Hence the *sum* of two differences of two integer squares can always be made to represent any number. For example, let $n \ge 1$ be the number, and let $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$ be any two numbers such that $a,b \not\equiv 2\!\pmod{4}$ and $a+b=n$. Then $a=a_1^2-a_2^2$ and $b=b_1^2-b_2^2$, and
$$n = a + b = (a_1^2-a_2^2)+(b_1^2-b_2^2) = (a_1^2+b_1^2)-(a_2^2+b_2^2).$$
This can be extended to any number of squares by choosing $n=a+b+c$ or $n=a+b+c+d$, and so on; your example is $n=a+b+c$.

So the answer to your question is basically "no"… although it might be a worthwhile paper if you showed the generalization(s), and found some interesting applications of the results.